# Functional Dependencies: Find the key and decomposition into BCNF and 3NF

Tags: functional-dependencies

Good Evening!

Consider the following relation R with the attributes: R={A, B, C, D, E, G, H, I, J, K} with FDs are:

```
F={AB → D, A → CE, B →G, G→HI, C→JK}
```

I want to find the key of R and decompose the relation into BCNF and 3NF. I tried to calculate the key by using the steps of algorithm of normalization as it is shown below

```
1. -
2. DEHIJK
3. ABG
4. ABG
```

So after the determination of the dependencies above I calculate the key is: `ABCDEG.`

But when I tried to verify this on this [site](http://www.koffeinhaltig.com/fds/kandidatenschluessel.php) the result was very different, and I confused over to decomposite into BCNF and 3NF. Can anyone help me to resolve this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: 1) That website doesn't work. Don't use it.
2) I don't understand how you tried to compute the candidate key, but your outcome is wrong. The **candidate** key is only `AB`. You should edit your question explaining in details how you tried to solve the problem, and where are you stuck.

Answer (score 0):

R has only one candidate key. It's AB.

You don't have to work hard to determine that AB is a candidate key. In each step we already know that the left-hand side is determined by {AB}.

```
FD    Attributes determined
--
AB->D {ABD}
A->CE {ABCDE}
B->G  {ABCDEG}
G->HI {ABCDEGHI}
C->JK {ABCDEGHIJK}
```

Read this as "AB determines D, therefore we know the attributes A, B, and D. A determines CE, therefore we know the attributes A, B, C, D (from previous step), and E." And so on.